# CSS Tab in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Please,

I'm trying to include a tab using CSS in my Visual Web Part without success.
Tested in Opera, Chrome and Firefox and both work but not in IE. Tested in versions 8, 9 and 11.

Can anyone tell me what could be wrong?

```
#content { padding: 25px; background: #FFF; }

#tabs {
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 205px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tabs-content {
    padding: 25px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
.tabs {
    overflow: hidden; 
    background: #e1e1e1; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #f2f2f2, #e1e1e1); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f2f2f2), color-stop(100%,#e1e1e1)); 
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; 
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF inset; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF inset; 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF inset;
}
.tabs a {
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    font: 15px/35px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; 
    padding: 0 20px 0 40px; 
    color: #999; 
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
    border-left: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    border-right: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tabs a:first-child {
    border-left-width: 0;
}
.tabs a:last-child {
    border-right-width: 0;
}
.tabs a:after {
    content: '✔';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 21px; 
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 7px 10px 5px 0; 
    background: #000; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 21px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 21px; 
    border-radius: 21px; 
    background: #bdbdbd; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #d4d4d4, #bdbdbd); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d4d4d4), color-stop(100%,#bdbdbd)); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #FFF, 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25) inset; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #FFF, 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25) inset; 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #FFF, 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25) inset; 
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999; 
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tabs a:hover {
    background: #FFF;
    border-left-color: #CCC;
}
.tabs a:hover:after {
    background: #038bd5; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #2dc3fc, #038bd5); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2dc3fc), color-stop(100%,#038bd5)); 
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #096c9e; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.45), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,148,255,0.85); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.45), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,148,255,0.85); 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.45), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,148,255,0.85)
}
.tabs a:hover + .tabs-content {
    display: block;
}
.tabs-content:hover {
    display: block;
}

<div id="tabs">
<nav class="tabs">
    <a href="#">About Scamper</a>
    <section class="tabs-content">
        Scamper is the coolest.
    </section>
    <a href="#">His Anatomy</a>
    <section class="tabs-content">
        Partly because he's a penguin.
    </section>
    <a href="#">Life Achievements</a>
    <section class="tabs-content">
        But also he had a movie made about him.
    </section>
    <a href="#">More Info</a>
    <section class="tabs-content">
        These tabs sure are great.
    </section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to get tabs to function with pure CSS, you may be better off generating the tab behavior with some JavaScript.

Here is a basic example that should work across all browsers:

```
<style>
ul#tabs { list-style-type: none; margin: 30px 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0.3em 0; }
ul#tabs li { display: inline; }
ul#tabs li a { color: #42454a; background-color: #dedbde; border: 1px solid #c9c3ba; border-bottom: none; padding: 0.3em; text-decoration: none; }
ul#tabs li a:hover { background-color: #f1f0ee; }
ul#tabs li a.selected { color: #000; background-color: #f1f0ee; font-weight: bold; padding: 0.7em 0.3em 0.38em 0.3em; }
div.tab { border: 1px solid #c9c3ba; padding: 0.5em; background-color: #f1f0ee;}
div.tab.hide { display: none; }
</style>
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#about">About Scamper</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anatomy">His Anatomy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#achievement">Life Achievement</a></li>
    <li><a href="#more">More Info</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab" id="about">
    Scamper is the coolest.
</div>
<div class="tab" id="anatomy">
    Partly because he's a penguin.
</div>
<div class="tab" id="achievement">
    But also he had a movie made about him.
</div>
<div class="tab" id="more">
    These tabs sure are great.
</div>
<script>
    var tabLinks = new Array();
    var contentDivs = new Array();
    var tabListItems = document.getElementById('tabs').childNodes;
    for ( var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++ ) {
        if ( tabListItems[i].nodeName == "LI" ) {
            var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
            var id = getHash( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
            tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
            contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById( id );
        }
    }
    /* Assign onclick events to the tab links and highlight the selected tab */
    var i = 0;
    var hash = window.location.hash.length > 0 ? getHash(window.location.hash) : "";
    for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
        tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
        tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
        if(hash != ""){
            if(hash == id){tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';}
        }
        else if ( i == 0 ){tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';}
        i++;
    }
    var i = 0;
    /* Hide all unselected content divs */
    for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
        if ( tabLinks[id].className != 'selected' ){ contentDivs[id].className = 'tab hide'}
        i++;
    }

function showTab() {
      var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );
      for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
        if ( id == selectedId ) {
          tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
          contentDivs[id].className = 'tab';
        } else {
          tabLinks[id].className = '';
          contentDivs[id].className = 'tab hide';
        }
          }
}
function getFirstChildWithTagName( element, tagName ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
        if ( element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName ) return element.childNodes[i];
    }
}
function getHash( url ) {
      var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
      return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
}
</script>
```